# c# GetInstalledVoices in a certain language

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I am able to get a list of all the voices installed on my Windows 10 system with:

```
var voiceCollection = synthesizer.GetInstalledVoices();
```

and I can get a list of installed voices from a certain locale with for example:

```
var voiceCollection = synthesizer.GetInstalledVoices(new CultureInfo("es-ES"));
```

The above line however would *not return* any installed `es-MEX` voices

My question is - Is there a way to get a list of all installed voices with a *certain language* - eg all the voices that are *Spanish*, regardless of their specific locale ?

Comment: I believe that would be `synthesizer.GetInstalledVoices(new CultureInfo("es"))` - as the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586870(v=vs.110).aspx) say _"Two-letter language codes such as "en" are also permitted."_

Comment: I'd seen this in the docs, but for some reason it doesn't work on my machine - always returns 0 results - Dmitry's Linq below works well for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general case, you can try using *Linq* in order to *filter out* the voices:

```
using System.Linq;

... 

List<InstalledVoice> voices = synthesizer
  .GetInstalledVoices()                                          // all voices
  .Where(voice => voice.VoiceInfo.Culture.Name.StartsWith("es")) // but filtered
  .ToList();                                                     // organized in a list
```

Comment: There is also `voice.VoiceInfo.Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName` if you want to check the language explicitly rather than looking for a prefix on the `Name`.